# CMD / Powershell отказывается запускать python файл

Tags: python, файлы, cmd, powershell

Проблема такая. CMD или Powershell не хотят запускать файл, хотя Python установлен, установлен в PATH, файл присутствует. Когда в Powershell запускаю Python файл, тот ноль вывода. 
[image: Запуск через Powershell]

В чём проблема?

Comment: А в скрипте вывод точно есть?

Comment: Да, я бы не задавал этот вопрос тогда

Comment: Покажите [mcve].

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c851228/v851228493/16b54d/wlVgN1ZIV2A.jpg Вот. Начало кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, стоит проверить как ЯП прописан? 
у меня запускается командой python3. 
Попробуйте запустить, указав прямой путь до питона. 
Таким образом отсечём проблемы с PATH

Comment: Ранее всё работало. Это нормально?
Обновлено: при python или python3 он кидает в ms store
Обновлено1: С указанием пути помогло, спасибо